# MYSQL select row before as previos data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This the example of the table name is merchant_point_log :

```
id    created_date   merchant_id   point_value   recent_point   status
 1    2022-01-02           1           5000           5000        earn 
 2    2022-01-02           2           3000           3000        earn
 3    2022-01-02           1           3000           3000        redeem
```

i would like to show logging like with previous recent point in one row like :

```
id    created_date  merchant_id   status   previous_point   point_value   recent_point   
 1    2022-01-02         1         in           0             5000           5000        
 2    2022-01-02         1         out         5000           3000           2000        
 3    2022-01-02         2         in          0              3000           3000
```

how do i return previos_point column from before row of selected data ?

i already tried this query but still doesn't work as expected :

```
select
mpl.id 
, mpl2.recent_point as previous_point
, mpl.point_value
, mpl.recent_point
from merchant_point_log mpl
left join merchant_point_log mpl2 on mpl.created_date = adddate(mpl2.created_date, 1)
order by mpl.id asc
;
```

the result is previous point dont return as expected it always repeat same value. I use mysql version 5.7

Answer (score 0):

We use `lag` to get `previous_point` and `coalesce` to put it as 0 in case `previous_point` `is null`.

```
select id 
      ,created_date
      ,case status when 'earn' then 'in' else 'out' end            as status
      ,coalesce(lag(recent_point) over (order by created_date), 0) as previous_point
      ,point_value
      ,recent_point
from   t
```

| id | created_date | status | previous_point | point_value | recent_point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | in | 0 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | in | 2000 | 5000 | 7000 |
| 3 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | out | 7000 | 3000 | 4000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YffawgRi?hide=2)

Comment: is there any alternative for over syntax for run in mysql ver 5.7 ?

Comment: @Diana check my other answer.

Comment: @Diana are the IDs always consecutive? If not, how do you decide what comes first when created_date is equal between two rows?

Comment: yes the id is consecutive, if the date are same the first row that come out is the smallest id

Comment: @Diana if that's the case then my  other solution would work as is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer with `left join` for older versions where window functions are not an option.

```
select   t.id 
        ,t.created_date
        ,case t.status when 'earn' then 'in' else 'out' end as status
        ,coalesce(t2.recent_point, 0)                       as previous_point
        ,t.point_value
        ,t.recent_point
from     t left join t t2 on t2.id = t.id-1
order by t.id
```

| id | created_date | status | previous_point | point_value | recent_point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | in | 0 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | in | 2000 | 5000 | 7000 |
| 3 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | out | 7000 | 3000 | 4000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZeB6WFm-?hide=4)